# Postgres users see different data

Tags: postgresql

I've been using MySQL for quite some time, and I've decided to learn Postgres. The transition hasn't been terrible, but I ran into a snag today:

I have the admin account, `postgres`, and a user specifically for this application, `tv`. For the sake of convenience, I was modifying some rows in a table under the admin account. The website would not reflect any of the changes I was making to the database.

After blaming my various caching strategies for about an hour I finally ran `psql` as the `tv` user and noticed that none of the rows in there reflected the alterations made while logged in as `postgres`. Coming from a MySQL background, this behavior was completely baffling to me.

Long story short: is this a feature, or did I misconfigure something somewhere? And is there any way to make the database not act like this?

Thanks for any help.

---

**Update:** Here are a sampling of commands:

```
[12:23:04] blake$ sudo -u postgres psql -d teevee
psql (9.1.3)
Type "help" for help.

teevee=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM episode;
 count
-------
     1
(1 row)
```

```
[12:23:25] blake$ psql -U tv -d teevee -h localhost -W
Password for user tv:
psql (9.1.3)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

teevee=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM episode;
 count
-------
   176
(1 row)
```

Comment: What you describe seems hardly possible. Are you sure you were changing the rows in the same database? In 99% of such cases it turns out to be a wrong connection. psql defaults to the database that is named as the user unless you specify something else. Please show us the **exact** commandline you used to start psql with the postgres user and the tv user.

Comment: You migth also want to run `select current_database();` when connected to both users to verify you are using the correct database.

Comment: Do the changes still show up under the postgres user?

Comment: I updated the post with a simple count select and the commands used to connect to the database.

Comment: Just in case, do the search paths differ? (`SHOW SEARCH_PATH;` You can also list the schemas available in `psql` with `\dn`.)

Comment: can you issue `select count(*) from public.episode;` just to rule out a non-default search_path?

Comment: Oh, it looks like they're on different schemas. postgres is using public and tv is using tv.

Comment: Do you have tables with the same name in the two schemas `tv` and `public`?

Comment: Since one client was using a socket and the other was using TCP, there was a slight possibility that they were talking to two different instances of postgres. This came to mind as one sanity check -- there might be a better one: select pg_postmaster_start_time(); -- executed in both clients, that should match :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can list schemas using `\dn` or `\dn+` under `psql`, but I would suggest using a tool like pgAdmin to have a better visual representation. You can find whether you have conflicting tables in those potential `tv` and `public` schemas using `\dt public.*` and `\dt tv.*`.

Using multiple [schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html) can be useful, but is often not required.

The default search path tends to be `"$user",public`, which means that it will first try to use the tables in the schema named after the user and fall back onto the `public` schema (the most common).

I would suggest using the `public` schema in general, unless you have a good reason not to. This should generally be the default. (I'm not sure why you had another schema.)

You can change a table schema [using `ALTER TABLE xxxxxx SET SCHEMA yyyyyyy`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html), although you may need to drop the other one with a conflicting name beforehand. You would certainly want to copy the data out first.

Something like `INSERT INTO public.episode SELECT * FROM tv.episode` should work in your case, even better with the column names specified. Whether this works may depend on other constraints.

If you have nothing useful in your `public` schema at the moment, you might as well drop the schema entirely ([`DROP SCHEMA public`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-dropschema.html)) and rename the other one ([`ALTER SCHEMA tv RENAME to public`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-alterschema.html)). Depending on what's already granted, you may then also need something like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO public;
```

Comment: I had a hacky little import script from MySQL that probably created the additional schema. The Drop, alter and grant sequence worked beautifully thanks.